# give a highlight colour in react-select on hovering over the options

Tags: react-select

I am using react-select package in my project with the below mentioned styles,

```
const customStyles = {
  option: (defaultStyles, state) => ({
    ...defaultStyles,
    color: state.isSelected ? "#0C5061" : "#fff",
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "#fff" : "#162E3E",
  }),

  control: (defaultStyles) => ({
    ...defaultStyles,
    backgroundColor: "#162E3E",
    padding: "3px",
    width: '17rem',
    border: "0.4px solid #FFFFFF",
    boxShadow: "none",
  }),
  singleValue: (defaultStyles) => ({ ...defaultStyles, color: "#fff" }),
};
```

i am not able to get a highlight on hovering over an options from the drop down is there something which can be done